# Asp.Net Core Mvc6 Claims Authorization is not persistent

Tags: asp.net-core, claims, asp.net-authorization

I am doing an Asp.Net Core Mvc 6 App where I dynamically assign Claims to the user.

I have in the database all Roles that a user must have to access specific fields of the page.

I also have the role of the user.

I am creating Claims where the user's role matches the field page User role. And then I create a ClaimsPrincipal with those list of Roles.

This are the data in the database

[image: data]

This is how I create the permission for the user..

```
 private string[] TransformRowsIntoPermissions(List<RolesAccessModel>? rows, string userRole)
        {
             List<string> permissionList = new();
            if(rows!=null)
            { 
                foreach (RolesAccessModel row in rows)
                {
                    if (row.Roles!=string.Empty && row.Roles != null && !row.Roles.Contains(userRole))
                        continue;

                       // if we get here we have a match
                       if (!permissionList.Contains(row.EventName))
                        permissionList.Add(row.EventName);
                }
            }

            return permissionList.ToArray(); 
        }
```

When I have the Permission List, I add it as Claims

```
  private Claim[] CreateClaimsFromArray(string[] permissions)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = new();
            foreach (var permission in permissions)
                claims.Add(new Claim(permission, "-"));

            return claims.ToArray();
        }
```

And in the main function I save it as ClaimPrincipal

```
   private async void CreateClaimsByUserRole(string role)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity =await _iUIConfig.CreateClaimsByUserRole(role);
            var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { claimsIdentity });
            _ = HttpContext.SignInAsync(userPrincipal);
        }
```

I do not know if line  `_ = HttpContext.SignInAsync(userPrincipal);` is necessary.

I checked `userPrincipal` and it has all the data.

[image: Claims]

What I need to do is to ask in the View for that claims in order to show or to not Show the fields.
But when I ask if it is null...

```
 @{
    var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
    if (claimsIdentity != null)
     {
       var c = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

       if (c != null)
       {
         <p>
                @c.Type.ToString();
                @c.Value.ToString();
          </p>
        }
        else
        {
          <p>
              null
          </p>
        }
     }
 }
```

It is null

If I ask for a specific value

```
@{ 
          if(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.ToList().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "DocumentId" && c.Value == "-") != null)
 {
                       .....
  }
```

}
Got an error `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Even If a call a Controller/Method and ask for

```
 var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
```

Is null..

I have to do it persistent for all the App.

I am not using Authentication because it is not implemented yet.. I am using SSO from another system. For that reason, for my understanding Cookie are used for Authentication.

In program.cs I only have

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminAccess", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));

    options.AddPolicy("ManagerAccess", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                    context.User.IsInRole("Admin")
                    || context.User.IsInRole("Manager")));

    options.AddPolicy("UserAccess", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                    context.User.IsInRole("Admin")
                    || context.User.IsInRole("Manager")
                    || context.User.IsInRole("User")));
});
```

and

```
app.UseAuthorization();
```

What am I missing to do it persistent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClaimsPrincipal.Current` was used in asp.net,however,in Asp.net core it is no longer set

To retrieve the current user in an ASP.NET Core MVC app,you could try with `ControllerBase.User` or`HttpContext.User`

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for more details

`SignInAsync` creates an encrypted cookie and adds it to the current response.You could get the claims after authenticating successfully in the following request untill the cookie expires(not the current request)

Notice `HttpContext.User` could be setted directly

And in View you could get the claims in @ section as below:

```
@{
    var claims = this.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
}
```